# JavaScript побитовый оператор

Tags: javascript

Каким образом

```
if(5&1) - возвращает true
if(4&1) - возвращает false
```

То есть четное - false, нечетное  - true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, фактически проверяется четность через проверку младшего бита.

У четных чисел младший бит не установлен, у нечетных - установлен.

Comment: Точно... Спасибо!